# Regex pattern using an | option

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to merge two regex patterns so as to use either one based on the text, but it isn't working:

```
test1 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^a-zA-Z]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

It works for `/nTotal_pass 3 1 -  -  - 4  Star Services Limited`. Then

```
test2 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^[\*]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

works for `/nTotal_pass 3 1 -  -  - 4  *Mount Services Limited`.

Output required:  `/nTotal_pass 3 1 -  -  - 4`

Merging the two codes:

```
test3 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass([^a-zA-Z]|[^\\*])*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

or

```
test3 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^\*]*).*|(Total_pass[^a-zA-Z]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()
```

What am I doing wrong?

The first code stops working as it encounters a `**` symbol while the second one works for (`**`)

Comment: Try `test1 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^*a-zA-Z]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()`. But do you know `[^[\*]` matches any char but `[` and `*`? Is that a typo? Did you mean `[^*]`, to match any char but `*`?

Comment: Show the code where you use the re.subs, and provide a sample string with expected output

Comment: 1 - well i have a whole set of text which i need to discard the very first time a word comes after the word Total_pass.  The concern is sometimes before the new word comes, it starts with a (*) like a disclaimer.. So that's why i'm trying to make use of both..

Comment: for example :                                                                                                                
This code - test1 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^a-zA-Z]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()   stops working at text :  **disclaimer...    i.e,(when the word starts with a *symbol)                                                                          test2 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^[\*]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip() works in this case(*)..  I'm trying to merge them so that it works in both case : when the word starts with a * and when it's just a normal word..

Comment: No, `[^A-Za-z]*` matches `*`, it cannot stop before `*`. Please update the question with more details.

Comment: I've update the question, please have a look..

Comment: You really have `/n` there? Not an LF char, a newline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may join the two negated character classes into one:

```
test3 = re.sub(r'(Total_pass[^*a-zA-Z]*).*', r'\1', test, flags=re.S).rstrip()
#                            ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eyIvDW/1)

**Details**

- `(Total_pass[^*a-zA-Z]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `Total_pass` - a literal text
  - `[^*a-zA-Z]*` - 0  or more characters other than asterisk and ASCII letters
- `.*` - any 0 or more characters to the end of the string.